# Identity relating Frobenius to multiplication by p on the ring of Witt vectors

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$, $F$ be the Frobenius map of Witt vectors, and $V$ the transfer map on $W(k)$. I'm trying to show that $FV(a) = pa$ where $a$ is a Witt vector. Clearly this is true in the case of $p$-adic numbers, since $F$ is the identity and $T$ is multiplication by $p$, but I'm struggling to prove the general case. Is the Frobenius map equivalent to the identity map on $W(k)$ in general?

Comment: This is just a formal manipulation. Check Prop 5.10 (1) of here: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~rabinoff/misc/witt.pdf